# Fonte da reputação branca

Tags: bug, status-pronto, reputação

Alguém mais notou que a cor da fonte da reputação que fica ao lado das medalhas está com a cor branca e por isso ficou quase invisível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é no topo, ao lado da barra de pesquisa.

Comment: Poxa vida, você foi mais rápido... Ia perguntar justamente isso, kkkk... Parece ser algo do estagiário...

Comment: poxa ainda bem que mais alguém viu, estava me sentindo discriminado.. kkk

Comment: Em vários lugares

Comment: Eles mexem nas coisas no SOEn e tão pouco ligando se altera algo nos internacionais, até alguém reclamar. SE sempre foi assim, o SOen funcionando bem, o resto que se ****.

Comment: Será que foi teste do estagiário? Brincadeira com os estagiários :)
No SO inglês continua escuro

Comment: Eu fiquei dando full f5 achando que era problema aqui... HAHAHAHAHA aff

Comment: Suposição minha, mas acho que eles mudaram a barra no topo dos outros sites da rede StackExchange... A barra ficou com um fundo escuro e a cor da reputação ficou branca. Parece que afetou [outras variantes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3546/el-nuevo-color-de-la-reputaci%C3%B3n-la-vuelve-indistinguible) da rede também...

Comment: Olá, eu não falo muito bem portuges, o mesmo acontece no site de espanhol, japonês e russo, criei um post em [meta.se] informando do problema: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311574/

Comment: Resolva isso executando na consola: `$("div[title^='sua rep']").css("color", "#000")`... mas se atualizar a página volta tudo de novo :P

Comment: verdade agora volto, mas @dvd é uma vergonha temos que fazer uns hacks pra usar o site :(

Comment: @RicardoPontual rsrs... na verdade meu comentário foi mais uma anedota pra descontrair. :)

Comment: ah entendi... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso foi corrigido. Obrigado por nos avisar!